# Indexed draw vs draw array

Tags: opengl, opengl-es2

Lately I wondered, which draw command is faster, `drawArrays` or `drawElements`. I know difference between them, `drawArrays` just draws every vertex in the same order they were provided, and `drawElements` draws vertices based on the provided indices. But I'm still curious which command is faster, or when should I use `drawArrays` instead of `drawElements` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends**.

Using glDrawElements requires an index buffer which is an extra, but does allow for removal of duplicate vertices, concatenation of primitives and reuse of vertices via the hardware vertex cache.

Using glDrawArrays is simpler but doesn't have these advantages.

Desktop hardware has been optimized around glDrawElements with GL_TRIANGLES for quite some time - [Quake 3 pushed it as the preferred rendering path](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake3/johnc_glopt.html), so that's the timescale we're talking about.

Some mobile hardware may still have glDrawArrays and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP as the optimal path.

As always, benchmark on your target platform(s).

Comment: Thank you, but if I wrote some wrapper around OpenGL ES 2. Should I use both?

Comment: @АйратНасыров - still the same answer: "it depends".  Hardware running ES2 is *probably* more likely to prefer glDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, but it depends on the *hardware*, not the OS, not the API, and other hardware may be different.